# Trigger form submit with multiple submit buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form with two submit buttons, Rails backend expects to receive one of the button names (`action1` or `action2`) in the `params` hash. I want to show "are you sure?" message on one of the buttons. I have this code:

```
<form action="/models" id="myform" method="post">
  <input name="action1" id="action1Button" type="submit" value="Make Action 1">
  <input name="action2" type="submit" value="Make Action 2">
</form>

  $('#action1Button').click(function() {
    $('#popup').modal('show');

    // cancel a submit
    return false;
  });

  $('#popupSubmitButton').click(function() {
    $('#myform').submit(); // I want this to trigger action1
  });

  $('#popupCancelButton').click(function(){
    $('#popup).modal('hide');
  });
```

The problem is that when form submits there is no name of the submitted button in the request. Is there a way to submit a form as though as submit button was actually clicked?

Comment: `$('#myform').submit(); // this should trigger action1` that is incorrect. it'l just submit the form with no action. you'll want to instead trigger the click event on the action 1 button in a way that bypasses the original event handler you provided.

Comment: Did you try `$('#action1Button').trigger('click')`

Comment: @adeneo infinite loop

Comment: @KevinB this is essentially my question. Is there a way to make this happen so that I don't have to track if popup window is opened/if button is clicked second time?

Comment: Yes, `$('#action1Button')[0].click()` might work, otherwise you could just create another button and hide action1button

Comment: @KevinB - No, that would still trigger the jQuery event handler.

Comment: Yup, that only works for the submit event then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger the event with `trigger()`, and in the event handler you can actually check if the event was triggered or not by checking `event.isTrigger`

```
$('#action1Button').on('click', function(e) {
    if (!e.isTrigger) {
        $('#popup').modal('show');
        return false;
    }
});

$('#popupSubmitButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#action1Button').trigger('click');
});

$('#popupCancelButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#popup').modal('hide ');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5FHZ6/)